# Rails and coffeescript, pass

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm trying to solve an issue with rails and js.

I have a button in my view

```
%button.action-button.floated.extra-small{:type => "button", data: {'save' => true, 'element' => @element_to_edit.class.to_s.underscore()}} Salva
```

And I have a javascript file

```
$('button[data-save]').on 'click', (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    html_meta_content = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData()
    $('#gate_meta_body').html(html_meta_content)
    $('form.visual-edit-form').submit()
    false
```

I want to make this javascript reusable: the problem is this line

```
$('#gate_meta_body')
```

where `gate` is related to my class (Gate). I need to change this according to my class. I'm tryng to pass the class in the button with

```
@element_to_edit.class.to_s.underscore()
```

But I don't understand how I can use the class value to change my javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Note two changes aded to the original code. 
1. 'element' value stored in HTML button ... data-element="your model name" is extracted using jQuery construct: 
element = $(this).data('element'). 
2. The extracted value is included ( as #{...} ) in 
$('##{element}_meta_body').

```
$('button[data-save]').on 'click', (event) ->
  element = $(this).data('element')
  event.preventDefault()
  html_meta_content = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData()
  $('##{element}_meta_body').html(html_meta_content)
  $('form.visual-edit-form').submit()
  false
```

Comment: A short explanation would make your answer more useful

Comment: Two changes aded to the original code. 1. 'element' value stored in <button ... data-element="your model name" ...> of your html is extracted using jQuery construct: element = $(this).data('element'). 2. The extracted value is included (using #{...})  in $('##{element}_meta_body'). No more changes added.